# Why getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataSource' of undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I drop this terrible error and i can't move forward When i want to click on my grid row i want to open window popup and try to show detail of that row. I'm showing detail with `LoadContentFrom` function but when i try double click on row . I get this error `Orpac.js:16197 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataSource' of undefined`

Here my Main view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    currentPageName = "LoyaltyCards";

});
</script>
@{
var columnList = ViewBag.List;

int[] series = new int[3];
series[0] = 50;
series[1] = 100;
series[2] = 200;
}
<script src="../../Scripts/kendo/2018.1.117/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/kendo/2018.1.117/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="Over" class="k-overlay" style="opacity: 0.5; z-index: 10000; display: none;"></div>
<header><h3><span id="lylheader">@ViewData["LoyaltyCards"]</span></h3></header>

<div class="k-rtl">
@( Html.Kendo().Grid<Orpac.Models.DATA>()
                         .Name("grdLoyaltyCards")
                         .DataSource(ds => ds
                         .Ajax()
                         .Read(r => r.Action("GridLoyaltyCardsBinding", "Loyalty").Type(HttpVerbs.Get)).PageSize(20)
                         )
                         .Columns(columns =>
                         {

                             columns.Bound(e => e.McrKod).Width(90).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' value='#=McrKod#'/>").Title((string)ViewData["Select"]).Filterable(false);
                             columns.Bound(e => e.McrKod).Width(200).Title((string)ViewData["CardNo"]).Encoded(false);
                             columns.Bound(e => e.CrdKod).Width(150).Title((string)ViewData["CardType"]);
                             columns.Bound(e => e.McrStatus).Width(150).Title((string)ViewData["Status"]);
                             columns.Bound(e => e.McrIsim).Width(150).Title((string)ViewData["Name"]);
                             columns.Bound(e => e.McrSoyad).Width(150).Title((string)ViewData["Surname"]);
                             columns.Bound(e => e.McrMail).Width(150).Title((string)ViewData["EMail"]);
                             columns.Bound(e => e.McrGsm).Width(150).Title((string)ViewData["Phone"]);
                             columns.Bound(e => e.McrBasla).Width(200).Title((string)ViewData["StartDate"]).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(McrBasla, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss') #");
                             columns.Bound(e => e.McrBitis).Width(200).Title((string)ViewData["EndDate"]);
                             columns.Bound(e => e.LstCode).Width(150).Title((string)ViewData["CustomerList"]);
                             columns.Bound(e => e.MegCode).Width(150).Title((string)ViewData["PointGroup"]);
                             columns.Bound(e => e.McrKimlikNo).Width(150).Title((string)ViewData["ID"]).Visible(false);

                         })
                                 .Events(events => events.DataBound("onRowDataBoundLoyalty").Change("ongrdLoyaltyRowSelect"))
                                 .ToolBar(toolBar =>
                                 {
                                     toolBar.Excel().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btnexcel" }).Text(" ").IconClass("k-i-excel");
                                     toolBar.Custom().Text((string)ViewData["SaveSettings"]).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-button", id = "savegrid", href = "#", onclick = "SaveColumnPosition()" });
                                     toolBar.Custom().Text((string)ViewData["ClearFilter"]).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-button", id = "cleargrid", href = "#", onclick = "clearFiltersLoyalty()" });
                                 }
                         )
                    .Excel(excel => excel.FileName((string)ViewData["LoyaltyCards"] + ".xlsx").AllPages(false).Filterable(true))
                    .Selectable()
                    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height("100%"))
                    .Sortable()
                    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                    .Refresh(true)
                    .PageSizes(series)
                    .ButtonCount(10))
                    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                    .Extra(false)
                    .Operators(operators => operators
                    .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                        .StartsWith("Starts with")
                        .Contains("Contains")
                    ))
                    )
                    .Groupable()
                    .Resizable(config =>
                    {
                        config.Columns(true);
                    })
                    .Reorderable(config =>
                    {
                        config.Columns(true);
                    })
                    .ColumnMenu()
)

  </div>
  <div class="k-rtl">
   @{ Html.Kendo().Window()
            .Name("LoyaltyWindow")
            .Title((string)ViewData["LoyaltyCards"])
            .Actions(b => b.Close())
            .LoadContentFrom("ContentOfLoyalty", "Loyalty") ////I WANT TO OPEN DETAIL FROM HERE
            .Modal(true)
            .Visible(false)
            .Draggable(true)
            .Resizable()
            .Width(1300)
            .Height(600)
            .Render();
     }
     </div>

    <script>
    $(function () {
        load();

        $('.k-grid-content', this).on('click', function (e) {
            var CategoryVisibility = "@ViewData["CategoryInLoyalty"].ToString()";
            openloyaltywindow(CategoryVisibility); ////HERE MY DOUBLE CLICK FUNCTION...


    $('#grdLoyaltyCards').on('change', ':checkbox', function (e) {
        var $check = $(this);
        if ($check.is(':checked')) {
            selectedLoyaltyCards.push($check.val());
        }
        else {
            selectedLoyaltyCards = $.grep(selectedLoyaltyCards, function (item, index) {
                return item != $check.val();
            });
        }

    });

    $("#grdLoyaltyCards").kendoTooltip({
        filter: "td",
        position: "right",
        content: "@ViewData["Tooltip"].ToString()"
    }).data("kendoTooltip");
})

function SaveColumnPosition() {
    var grid = $("#grdLoyaltyCards").data("kendoGrid");
    localStorage["kendo-grid-options-loyaltycard"] = kendo.stringify(grid.getOptions());
}

function load() {
    var grid = $('#grdLoyaltyCards').data("kendoGrid");
    var toolBar = $("#grdLoyaltyCards .k-grid-toolbar").html();

    var options = localStorage["kendo-grid-options-loyaltycard"];
    if (options) {
        grid.setOptions(JSON.parse(options));
        $("#grdLoyaltyCards .k-grid-toolbar").html(toolBar);
        $("#grdLoyaltyCards .k-grid-toolbar").addClass("k-grid-top");
    }
}
```

Here my Detail view

```
@{
var columnList = ViewBag.List;

int[] pageseries = new int[3];
pageseries[0] = 50;
pageseries[1] = 100;
pageseries[2] = 200;
}
@{Html.Kendo().TabStrip().Name("LoyaltyTab").Animation(enable => enable.Open(effects => effects.Expand(ExpandDirection.Vertical)))
              .Events(events => events.Select("selectLoyaltyTab"))
              .Items(item1 =>
              {
                  item1.Add().Text((string)ViewData["Overview"]).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "first" }).Selected(true).Visible((bool)ViewData["ShowOverview"]).Content(@<text>


<h3><b>@ViewData["Overview"]  <span id="daylabel"></span></b></h3>
<div>
    Select Year : @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox().AutoBind(false)
    .Name("cmbyear")
    .DataValueField("YearId")
    .DataTextField("YearText")
    .DataSource(binding => binding.Read(read =>
    {
         read.Action("CmbBindYear", "Loyalty");
              }))
        .Value(ViewData["YearNow"].ToString())
        .Events(e => e.Change("changeloyaltyyear"))
    )
</div>

<h3><b> @ViewData["CustomerInformation"]</b></h3>
<div style=" float:left;">
    <br />
    <h3><b>@ViewData["Questionare"]</b></h3>
    @*<div id="grdQuestionar"></div>*@
    @( Html.Kendo().Grid<DATA>()
                                                              .Name("grdLoyalty")
                                                              .DataSource(ds => ds
                                                              .Ajax()
                                                              .Read(r => r.Action("GridLoyaltyBinding", "Loyalty"))
                                                              )
                                                              .Columns(columns =>
                                                              {
                                                                  columns.Bound(e => e.Question).Title("Question");
                                                                  columns.Bound(e => e.Answer).Title("Answer");
                                                              })
                                                              .AutoBind(false)
                                                              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 300px; height:100%;" })
                                                              .Selectable()
                                                              .Sortable()
    )

</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-left: 50px;margin-top: -50px;">
    @{Html.Kendo().Chart<Orpac.Models.Mg_Web_LoyaltyTrxCount_Result>()
              .Name("loyaltytrxlist").Title((string)ViewData["TranChart"])
              .Legend(legend => legend
                          .Visible(true).Position(Kendo.Mvc.UI.ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
                                  .Labels(labels =>
                                  {
                                                      labels.Template("#= text #");
                                                  }
                          )
              ).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 500px; height:300px;" })
              .ChartArea(configurator => configurator.Background("transparent"))
              .DataSource(ds =>
              {
                                  ds.Read(read => read.Action("LoyaltyTransactionsPerYear", "Loyalty", new { year = DateTime.Now.Year }));
                              }).AutoBind(false)
              .Series(series =>
              {
                                  series.Line(data => data.Number_Of_Transactions);
                                  series.Line(data => data.Sum_of_Quantity);
                              })
              .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                  .Categories(data1 => data1.Monthstr)
              )
              .Theme((string)ViewData["themes"])
              .ValueAxis(axis => axis
                  .Numeric().Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0}"))
              )
              .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                  .Visible(true)
                  .Format("{0}")
              ).Render();
    }
</div>


<div style="clear: both;"></div>

                </text>);

              item1.Add().Text((string)ViewData["Transactions"]).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "third" }).Visible((bool)ViewData["ShowTran"]).Content(@<text>
@( Html.Kendo().Grid<Orpac.Models.Mg_Web_LylHarGet_Result>()
                                            .Name("grdLoyaltyTransaction")
                                    .DataSource(ds => ds
                                    .Ajax()
                                            .Read(r => r.Action("GridLoyaltyTransactionBinding", "Loyalty").Type(HttpVerbs.Get)).PageSize(20).Aggregates(agg =>
                                            {
                                                      agg.Add(a => a.MshTutar).Sum();
                                                      agg.Add(a => a.MshMiktar).Sum();
                                                      agg.Add(a => a.MshIskonto).Sum();
                                                      agg.Add(a => a.PuanBakiye).Sum();
                                                  })
                                    )
                                            .ToolBar(toolBar =>
                                            {
                                                      toolBar.Custom().Text(" ").Url(Url.Action("ExportCsvTranLoyalty", "Loyalty", new { page = 1, pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~" })).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btnexcel" });
                                                      toolBar.Custom().Text("Clear Filter").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-button", id = "cleargrid", href = "#", onclick = "clearFiltersTranLoyalty()" });
                                                  }
                                        )
                                    .Columns(columns =>
                                    {
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.MshIdent).Visible(false);
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.MshTxnTim).Title("Transaction " + (string)ViewData["Date"]).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(MshTxnTim, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm') #").ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("Transaction Date: #=  kendo.toString(value, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm') #");
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.MshMagazaNam).Title((string)ViewData["Station"]);
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.MshStok).Title((string)ViewData["StockNam"]);
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.MshTutar).Title((string)ViewData["Amount"]).ClientTemplate("#= FormatMoney(MshTutar) #").Encoded(true);
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.MshMiktar).Title((string)ViewData["Quantity"]);
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.MshTipName).Title((string)ViewData["Transaction"] + (string)ViewData["Tip"]);
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.iskontotipiName).Title((string)ViewData["Discount"] + (string)ViewData["Tip"]);
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.MshIskonto).Title((string)ViewData["Discount"]).ClientTemplate("#= FormatMoney(MshIskonto) #").Encoded(true);
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.PuanBakiye).Title((string)ViewData["Point"]);
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.MshCmpKod).Title((string)ViewData["Campaign"] + (string)ViewData["Tip"]);
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.MshIdent).Title((string)ViewData["TransactionId"]);
                                              columns.Bound(e => e.MshTarih).Title((string)ViewData["Account"] + (string)ViewData["Date"]).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(MshTarih, 'dd.MM.yyyy') #").ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("Account Date: #=  kendo.toString(value, 'dd.MM.yyyy') #");

                                          })
                                    .AutoBind(false)
                                    .Selectable()
                                .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Height(600))
                                .Sortable()
                                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                                .Refresh(true)
                                .PageSizes(pageseries)
                                .ButtonCount(10))
                                .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                                .Extra(false)
                                .Operators(operators => operators
                                .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                                    .StartsWith("Starts with")
                                    .Contains("Contains")
                                ))
                                )
                                .Groupable()
                                .Resizable(config =>
                                {
                                          config.Columns(true);
                                      })
                                .Reorderable(config =>
                                {
                                          config.Columns(true);
                                      })
                                .ColumnMenu()
)
            </text>);

                 }).Render();
   }
```

Here my _Layout.cshtml head part

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="author" content="Şaul Yaşar CEMAL" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2018.1.117/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2018.1.117/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2018.1.117/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2018.1.117/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/bower_components/metisMenu/src/metisMenu.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/Orpac.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../js/accounting.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../js/numeral.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.equalHeight.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here my js file

```
function openloyaltywindow(CategoryVisibility) {
var vCategory = CategoryVisibility;
$("#pointval").hide();
$("#discountval").hide();
$("#redemptionval").hide();

var grid = $('#grdLoyaltyCards').data("kendoGrid");
var dataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());

$("#daylabel").text("1/1/" + (new Date()).getFullYear() + " - " + (new Date).getDay() + "/" + ((new Date).getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (new Date()).getFullYear());

$("#yearid").text((new Date()).getFullYear());

var thisyear = (new Date()).getFullYear();

var combo = $("#cmbyear").data('kendoComboBox');
combo.dataSource.read(); // I'M GETTING ERROR FROM HERE ALL KENDO WIDGETS ARE UNDEFINED...

$("#lpname").html(dataItem.McrIsim);
$("#lpsname").html(dataItem.McrSoyad);
$("#lpcardtype").html(dataItem.CrdKod);
$("#lpcardnumber").html(dataItem.McrKod);
$("#lpcardstatus").html(dataItem.McrStatus);
$("#lpcstlist").html(dataItem.LstCode);
$("#lpgroup").html(dataItem.MegCode);

$("#lyltxtname").val(dataItem.McrIsim);
$("#lyltxtsname").val(dataItem.McrSoyad);
$("#lyltxtemail").val(dataItem.McrMail);
$("#lyltxtphone").val(dataItem.McrGsm);
$("#lyltxtid").val(dataItem.McrKimlikNo);


var todayDate = dataItem.McrBasla;
var date = todayDate.getDate();
var month = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = todayDate.getFullYear();

var invdate = date + "/" + month + "/" + year + " ";

$("#lpstartdate").html(invdate);
$("#lpenddate").html(dataItem.McrBitis);

$("#LoyaltyTab").data("kendoTabStrip").select(0);
$('#LoyaltyWindow').data('kendoWindow').maximize().open();
$("#LoyaltyWindow").closest(".k-window").css({
    top: 0,
    left: 0
});


var chart = $("#loyaltytrxlist").data('kendoChart');
chart.dataSource.read();
chart.refresh();

if (vCategory == "Yes") {
    var chartpie = $("#loyaltypie").data('kendoChart');
    chartpie.dataSource.read();
    chartpie.refresh();
}


var grid = $("#grdLoyalty").data('kendoGrid');
grid.dataSource.read();

$.ajax({
    url: '../Loyalty/GetPointsForCard',
    data: { card: dataItem.McrKod, pyear: thisyear },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {

            //do something


        }
        else {

        }
    }
}); 
}
```

Comment: DO you know where abouts in the code this is thrown? If it is in the `js` file my advice would be to put a debugger in there and use Google DevTools to see if it has a value

Comment: @JamesS yes it's in JS file but unfortunately kendo is undefined i did that

Answer (score 0):

you need to wait until the widgets are initialized, try putting your code inside this:

```
$(window).load(function () { //your js code}
```

Comment: Sorry this is not my solution... @Edgar

Comment: okei, try removing the kendo js reference in your main view, you already have it in your layout, in the kendo troubleshoot they say this could occur if the jquery lib is loaded again, check that

Comment: other thing that i see is that you are not initializing jquery in your layout or at least i cannot see it, as it is said in the documentation you need to declare the jquery lib before the kendo js libs

Comment: If you check Layout.cshtml you can see i added <script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2018.1.117/jquery.min.js"></script> @Edgar